# Screening out negatives before taking average

Tags: python, average, multiple-columns

I have this program to read in data, average across a row of three and then average down columns, so far it does all this fine. However I am now trying to go back and have it take out negative data points and I'm having some trouble:

```
from __future__ import division
import csv
v = open("Pt_2_Test_Data.csv", 'wb') #created file to write output to
A =[]
B = []
with open("test2.xls") as w:
    w.next()  # skip over header row
    for row in w:
        (date, time, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t,
         u, LZA, SZA, LAM) = row.split("\t")  # split columns into fields

        A.append([(float(a) + float(b) + float(c))/3,
         (float(d) + float(e) + float(f))/3,
         (float(g) + float(h) + float(i))/3,
         (float(j) + float(k) + float(l))/3,
         (float(m) + float(n) + float(o))/3,
         (float(p) + float(q) + float(r))/3,
         (float(s) + float(t) + float(u))/3])

def mean(B):
        return sum(B) / len(B)
for x in A:
        if x > 0:
                B.append(x)

print B
C = map(mean, zip(*B))
print C    

v.close()
```

(I'm not worried about writing the data to the file yet, just getting rid of the negatives before the final average is taken.)

Comment: You could do this much more simply using [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), which basically does much of what your code does, and manipulating numerical arrays is what `numpy` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you mean, but you can make a change to your mean function like so:

```
def mean(B):
        positives = [b for b in B if b >= 0] 
        return sum(positives) / len(positives)
```

This will give you the average of the non-negative members of B. Is this kind of what you were looking for?

In general, that comprehension is one way to get the non-negative members of a list. Another way, which makes more sense to me, is

```
filter (lambda i: i >=0, some_list)
```

This seems to be undergoing some deprecation, though.

Comment: yes! however I am getting this error 'return sum(positives) / len(positives)
ZeroDivisionError: float division'

Comment: You need to catch the case where positives is empty. `if positives: return sum(positives)/len(positives) else: return 0`